# why the width of col in bootstrap include padding

Tags: css, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

According to the W3school, heigh and width does not include padding and margin, however ,in the bootstrap, the col-*-*, let's say, col-md-3 will set the width= 25%, but this include the padding ,why?

```
<div class="text-center">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="well">.col-md-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="well">.col-md-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="well">.col-md-4</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

the width of each col is 33.33%*width of row =436.67px,

[the width of col](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69ikH.png)

[the layout of col](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEuKi.png)

according to the layout of each col, we can see that the actual width(436.67px) =padding + width of content. i thought the content width should be 436.67px? why am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap css there is a rule:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Under that rule the `width` is calculated with `content width + border + padding`. See [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)